# Can wp-cli display all users and their roles across all sites in a multisite instance?

Tags: multisite, user-roles, wp-cli, multisite-user-management

### List Multisite Users

Using **wp-cli**<sup>(1)</sup> If I run **`wp user list`** I get a list of the users (2 admins in my case) at the top level of multisite<sup>(2)</sup>.
[image]

### List Multisite Sites' Users

I have 25 sites with various users. Some users are in different sites as different roles.
When I use the network flag **`wp user list --network`** I get the same style report minus the **roles** column; but the report spans the multisite network of sites.
[image]

### List Multisite Sites' Users+Roles

My goal is to list all the admins of each site. This is where I am stuck. Apparently, adding the additional flag **`--role=administrator`** adds nothing to the conversation. It will run the same network report of all registered users.

Is there a combination of flags that will list the users along with their roles?

---

References:

1. wp-cli.org
2. codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite

*Side note: Dividing these up by site would also be handy.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**List all the admins of each site**

> Side note: Dividing these up by site would also be handy.

*Let's do that here:*

We can list the *url* of each site with:

```
wp site list --field=url
```

We can list all *administrators* of a given site with:

```
wp user list --role=administrator --url=https://example.tld/site1
```

These commands can be combined with e.g. `xargs` as suggested on the wp-cli [site](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/shell-friends/):

```
wp site list --field=url  \
  | xargs -I % wp user list --role=administrator --url=%
```

<strike>We might also want to use `| tail --lines=+2` to skip the *url* header, of the first command as explained in the tail manual and answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185599/2078474).</strike>

Thanks to @grappler for suggesting `--field="url"` instead of `--fields="url"` with `| tail --lines=+2` to skip the header row.

If we want to display the *url* before each table:

```
for url in $( wp site list --field="url" ); \
do \
   echo $url; \
   wp user list --role=administrator --url=$url; \
done;
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I am closer now. This is what I am getting
[now](http://imgur.com/a/pHrk6).

Comment: You're welcome. I updated with a way to display the url before each table @nic

Comment: Perfect! You couldn't have been more helpful. I think I fall in love with the terminal a little more every day. I've served this up as a script the rest of my team can use in the `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Glad to hear it helped and I agree with you, it's great to be able to work with WordPress through the command line  ;-) @nic

Comment: @birgire If you just use `--field=url` then you don't need to use `| tail --lines=+2`. It is field instead of fields. Singular not plural.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion @grappler, I updated the answer.